# How to read only a part of a string to obtain a drive's serial number?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string with hard drive volume information (the message is displayed in a message box)

> Volume In Drive E is NEW VOLUME
>   Volume Serial Number is 9AE4-F468

I want to read only "9AE4F468" without the dash, and display it in a message box.

I tried using `Substring(45,54)`, but I keep getting a compilation error because the program is not reading it.

How can I retrieve that particular substring without the dash?

Comment: Keep getting in compilation?? A word missing? Errors maybe??

Comment: Please show us the actual code you're using as well as the errors you're getting.

Comment: Pseudo code: substr(strlen(string)-8,strlen(string);

Comment: And if you're using Substring, keep in mind it's not (from, to) but (from, length) for the arguments.

Comment: He accidentally the internet

Comment: Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than being in the position where you have to use a substring to get at the disk volume serial number, you *could* use a method that gives you the correct string directly.

To use the following code, you must add to your assembly a reference to `System.Management` and then add a `using System.Management` to the top of the code file.

Then add this method:

```
public string DiskVolumeSerialNumber(char driveLetter)
{
    ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"" + driveLetter +":\"");
    disk.Get();
    return disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
string serial = DiskVolumeSerialNumber('C');
Console.WriteLine(serial);
```

Comment: There's also DiskInfo in System.IO.

Comment: yeah this much much better!! Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: @It'sNotALie I think you mean `DriveInfo`, but that only tells you the volume label, not the serial number (which is a different thing).

Comment: Beware of the WMI-Injection vulnerability :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oh, fair enough.

Comment: @JohannBlais Note that the only parameter passed to DiskVolumeSerialNumber() is a char, so that's going to be pretty safe, even if you just pass user input straight to it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the last word only:

```
string lastWordNoDash = 
    myLongMessage.Substring(myLongMessage.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1).Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: @GastonBaladi Do you understand why this works, why what you had didn't work, and why you got the errors you got? You might still want to improve your question based on the comments you received.

Comment: @Bart It worked fine and yes I do NOW understand how the solution given to me work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the last word then shadow wizard solve the problem.

if you're having more then you can do

```
string lineNeeded = "Volume Serial Number is ";
string lastWordNoDash = 
    myLongMessage.Substring(myLongMessage.IndexOf(lineNeeded) + lineNeeded.length, 9).Replace("-", "");
```